# How to derive marginal likelihood from prior and likelihood

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, likelihood

Given the following:

- X|θ ~ N(θ , 1/k)
- model M<sub>0</sub> stating that θ = θ<sub>0</sub>
- model M<sub>1</sub> stating that θ ~ N(u , 1/z)

**How to show that X|M<sub>1</sub> follows a normal distribution with mean u and variance 1/k + 1/z?**

I think I get the intuition behind it, X is centered around θ, and θ is centered around u, so X should have expectation u as well. And the variance sums up because under M<sub>1</sub> there's the variance for θ, and once θ is fixed there's variance around θ for X.

However, I'm struggling to formalize this intuition.

- The law of total expectation says E[E[X|θ]] = E[X] = u, but then how do I get from E[X] = u to E[X|M<sub>1</sub>] = u?
- Trying to calculate the marginal likelihood using the explicit PDFs was rather messy which I would prefer to avoid: f(X|M<sub>1</sub>) = ∫ f(X|θ) f(θ|M<sub>1</sub>) dθ

Thank you!

Comment: Your model is a normal-normal conjugate, a [standard case of Bayesian analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/526063).

Answer (score 4):

You have to start from first principles and work with definitions in order to produce a mathematically legit outcome. Intuition does not suffice.

The marginal density of the sample $X$ under model $\mathfrak M_1$ is given by the integral
\begin{align}
m_1(x) &= \int_\mathbb R f(x|\theta)\cdot \pi(\theta)\,\text d\theta\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \dfrac{e^{-(x-\theta)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\dfrac{e^{-z(u-\theta)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi/z}}\,\text d\theta\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x^2/2-zu^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\dfrac{e^{-(z+1)\theta^2/2+(x+zu)\theta}}{\sqrt{2\pi/z}}\,\text d\theta\tag{1}\\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2-zu^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \dfrac{e^{-(\theta-(x+zu)/(z+1))^2/2+(x+zu)^2/2(z+1)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\text d\theta\\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{(z+1)2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2-zu^2/2+(x+zu)^2/2(z+1)}\\&= \dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{(z+1)2\pi}}e^{-z(x-u)^2/2(z+1)}
\end{align}
Equivalently, it follows from the general result that the marginal distributions attached to a joint Normal distribution are Normal. Since $(X,\theta)$ is jointly normal (as shown by the integrand in (1)), $X$ is marginally Normal with mean
$$\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|\theta]]=\mathbb E[\theta]=u$$
and variance
$$\mathrm{var}(X)=\mathrm{var}(\mathbb E[X|\theta])+\mathbb E[\mathrm{var}(X|\theta)]=\mathrm{var}(\theta)+\mathbb E[1]=z^{-1}+1=\dfrac{z+1}{z}$$

Comment: But $E[\text{var}(X|\theta)]=E[\frac{1}{k}]=\frac{1}{k}$

Comment: @ADAM: I hope you can make the correction for $k\ne 1$ then.